# MailMerge: From Excel to Word Saving Individual Documents for Each Record While Maintaining Link to Source

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

First I want to say I am extremely new to utilizing VBA to make my excel sheets more efficient.

I started a few months back and mainly generate code by piecing together what I find online then edit to meet my specific needs.

What Current Code Does:

What I have created allows me to perform a multiple document mailmerge from excel to merge records from my datasoure (Project Information) with the click of a button. Before performing the merge, the user identifies 5 conditions;

1. Zoning (ex. R20; located in cell C8)
2. Easement Type (ex. TE; located in cell F8)
3. The Template to use from the previously uploaded template list (located in cell J8)
4. The Area of the Lot (located in cell P8)
5. If it is a just compensation Report ("yes" or "no" located in cell C11)

The criteria above identifies the record numbers that match the specified criteria to create individual mailmerge documents for each record and saves in the corresponding property file which is associated with the record number. The sheet that is generating mailmerge ("report Creation") is different from the datasource and maintains records of when the mailmerge was performed and what template was used. This sheet also contains the list of records and is the search range for the criteria (record start on line 39 so +37 is used to match "Report Creation" row).The code also contains a loading bar that appears when the merging is being performed and shows percentage complete (percentage is not correct but used more to show user merge is in progress).

My Question:

What I am now trying to adjust is when the mailmerge is performed I still want the individual documents but I want to maintain the link between the new document and the datasource. That way I can always update the word document if any changes occur. It currently merges to a word document that no longer contains any mailmerge field and is as if I finalized a merge.

I am assuming this is a minor change after the .opendatasource but cant pinpoint what to change.

My Code may be a bit messy and could definitely use some cleanup but it gets the job done. See below.

Current Code:

```
Sub RunMerge()

Dim StrMMSrc As String, StrMMDoc As String, StrMMDocName As String, StrName As String, dataname As String  
Dim i As Long  
Dim Load As Integer  
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application  
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document  
Dim ReportNum, AddressName, SaveLoc, NewFile, fpath, subfldr, DateCr As String  
Dim ExpTemp, ExTempDate, ExpReview, ExpRevDate As Range  
Dim ExpRow, CustCol, lastRow, StrMMDocRow, ExportedDoc, LotSizeSM, LotSizeLG, ActualLS, symbpos As Long  
Dim FileName, Zoning, Ease, LotSizeRNG, Ztype, Etype As String  

On Error GoTo errhandler

'Turn off at the start
TurnOffFunctionality
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone


Set wsreports = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Creation")  
Set wsinfo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Information")  
Set wsdetails = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Details")  
StrMMSrc = ThisWorkbook.fullname  
lastRow = wsinfo.Columns("A").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows,   LookIn:=xlValues).row  

    dataname = wsinfo.Name  

    'set folder path for saving documents  
    fpath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project Details").Range("E30").Value  
    subfldr = wsdetails.Range("F34").Value  

    'date exported  
    DateCr = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")  

ExportedDoc = 0


With wsreports


    ' set range criteria  
    LotSizeRNG = .Range("P8").Value  
    symbpos = InStr(1, LotSizeRNG, "<>")  

    LotSizeSM = CInt(Left(LotSizeRNG, symbpos - 1))  
    LotSizeLG = CInt(Mid(LotSizeRNG, symbpos + 2))  

If LotSizeLG = "" Then LotSizeLG = 100000000

    If wsreports.Range("J8").Value = Empty Then  
        MsgBox "Please Select A Template From The Dropdown List to Export"  
        wsreports.Range("J8").Select  
        GoTo errhandler  
    End If  

    StrMMDocRow = .Application.Match(Range("J8").Value, .Range("C1:C34"), 0) 'Set Template Row  
    StrMMDocName = .Range("J8").Value 'set template name  
    Zoning = .Range("C8").Value 'set Zoning Criteria  
    Ease = .Range("F8").Value 'Set Easement Criteria  
    StrMMDoc = .Range("AB" & StrMMDocRow).Value 'Word Document Filename  

End With  

wdApp.Visible = False  

Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=StrMMDoc, AddToRecentFiles:=False)  

With wdDoc  

    With .MailMerge  
            .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters  
            .OpenDataSource Name:=StrMMSrc, AddToRecentFiles:=False, LinkToSource:=False,  
 ConfirmConversions:=False, _  
                    ReadOnly:=True, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto,   Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _  
                    "User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & StrMMSrc & ";Mode=Read;Extended   Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";", _  
                    SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Project Information$`", SQLStatement1:="",   SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess  

    UserFormLoad.Show  

    For i = 2 To lastRow  

        Ztype = wsreports.Range("D" & i + 37).Value  
        Etype = wsreports.Range("F" & i + 37).Value  
        ActualLS = wsreports.Range("E" & i + 37).Value  

        'Check the row for matching zone and easement cristeria  
        If wsreports.Range("C11").Value = "No" And StrMMDocName <> wsreports.Range("H" & i + 37).Value _  
            And Ztype = Zoning And ActualLS >= LotSizeSM And ActualLS <= LotSizeLG And Etype = Ease Then    

            ExportedDoc = ExportedDoc + 1  

            'set newfile location  
            ReportNum = wsreports.Range("B" & i + 37).Value  
            AddressName = wsreports.Range("C" & i + 37).Value  
            SaveLoc = fpath & "\#" & ReportNum & "_" & AddressName & "\" & subfldr  

            'generate new file name with date  
            NewFile = SaveLoc & "\" & AddressName & "_Draft Report_" & DateCr & ".docx"  

            .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument  
            .SuppressBlankLines = True  

                With .DataSource  
                    .FirstRecord = i - 1  
                    .LastRecord = i - 1  
                    .ActiveRecord = i - 1    
                    StrName = NewFile  
                End With  

                .Execute Pause:=False  

                wsreports.Range("I" & i + 37).Value = StrMMDocName  
                wsreports.Range("L" & i + 37).Value = DateCr  

                With wdApp.ActiveDocument  
                    .SaveAs FileName:=StrName, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False  
                    ' and/or:  
                    '.SaveAs Filename:=StrMMPath & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False  
                    .Close savechanges:=False  
                End With  


            Dim r As Integer  

            r = i  

            Load = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((r + 1) / (lastRow) * 100, 0)  
            DoEvents  
            UserFormLoad.LoadBar.Width = Load / 100 * 222  
            UserFormLoad.LabelProg.Caption = Load & "%"  

            End If  

        Next i  

        Unload UserFormLoad  

        .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument  
    End With  
    .Close savechanges:=False  
End With  

If ExportedDoc = 0 Then  
MsgBox "No Properties Matched The Criteria Specified. Use The Table To Verify The Easement and Zoning   Have Properties Meeting Criteria.", vbOKOnly, "No Matches Found"  
Else  
MsgBox "The Property Draft Reports Were Exported Successfully. Please Check Project Property" & subfldr &  " Folder for Word Document.", vbOKOnly, "Export Successfull"
End If  

'cleanup if error  
errhandler:  
    TurnOnFunctionality  
    wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll  

    Set wdDoc = Nothing  
    Set wdApp = Nothing  

End Sub
```

Comment: To maintain a mail merge link in each individual file you may have to copy the source mail merge document for each individual document (not simply run actual mail merge).

Comment: @Parfait So i would essentially be creating numerous copies of the template file by performing a saveas with the associated record number? Not sure if it is possible but would I be able to perform the mailmerge and maintain the insert fields? That way if the mailmerge field is still intact I could reestablish the datasource to then update the fields. Do you know if theres a way to do that?

Comment: Try commenting out `.Execute Pause:=False`. Do you get individual documents with mail merge enabled?

Comment: «To maintain a mail merge link in each individual file you may have to copy the source mail merge document for each individual document (not simply run actual mail merge).» All that will do is generate a series of new mailmerge main documents that are linked to *all* records, not to a particular record.

Comment: @Parfait So I gave this a shot and it does generate an individual document that is still linked to the datasource and when the document is opened the appropriate record is appearing (preview is not enabled and has to be done manually from the mail merge ribbon). However, there is an error at line '.MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument' saying the the object has been deleted. Do you know what the cause of this is and how to resolve it?

Comment: All you have saved is a preview. Previews are not a reliable representation of the output generated by an actual merge.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use mailmerge for what you want to achieve. You would need to use LINK fields instead of MERGEFIELDs and update the LINK field row references for each output document.

An alternative approach would be to re-run the mailmerge for just the record(s) you want to update.

Comment: I have done some linking with excel table in word documents and I have had some issues in the past. Is there an efficient way to do what you are referring to? The alternative approach would not work with my current situation since the document I am generating is meant to be a base document to then fill in the remaining area within the report. So I am adding photos and other report specific information that I need to exclude from the template. Using the mailmerge function for way more than it is intended to do.

Comment: As I said, you'd replace the MERGEFIELDs with LINK fields whose row references you'd update. That said, mailmerges can insert images and variable content also - all you need do is provide the relevant parameters. See the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html